# Using Facebook Share link , didn't redirect to original site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-sharer

I try to make a facebook share function using link_to method.

This my share link helper

```
urlencode=ERB::Util.url_encode("http://fbjstest.herokuapp.com/posts/#{id}&t=#{title}");
url= "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=#{urlencode}"
```

It will make a url like this.

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://fbjstest.herokuapp.com/posts/9&t=Cool
```

My Problem is :

## When I click cancel or submit button , it didn't redirect to original website.

Any Suggestions ?

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I find the root cause...

I try to open the link on "new page" , It solve my problem.

```
<%= link_to 'Share to FB' , fb_share_link_maker(params[:id],@post.title) , :target => "_blank", :class => "btn" %>
```

Key point is

```
:target => "_blank"
```

Thanks